# How can I remove colon (:) from API URL in React project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to fetch data from an API, with dynamic id. I have colon in my Route path. After debugging the issue, I noticed that the colon is being included before the id in the link hence the failed fetch request. Please how can I resolve this. What I mean is, instead of ap1.yoursite.com/111 I'm sending request to ap1.yoursite.com/:111 which is causing the fetch object to remain null. How can I make the colon does its work as dynamic path, but does not interfere with my URL?

//My Route and // Fetch snippet

```
const Main = props => (
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Goods} />
    <Route path="/items:id" component={SingleGoods} />
  </Switch>
);

const { id } = this.props.match.params;
console.log(id); //returns :number
fetch(`http://api.yoursite/${id}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => this.setState({ show: json }));

console.log(this.state.show); //always returns null, which is the initial state
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you correctly, but I think:

```
<Route path="/items:id" component={SingleGoods} />
```

should be

```
<Route path="/items/:id" component={SingleGoods} />
```

with another slash in the path.

Comment: I am very stupid. How can I make such a simple mistake, and have been debugging my code for several hours. Thankssss.

Answer (score 1):

Try `<Route path="/items/:id" component={SingleGoods} />`, note the '/' before the parameter.

[react-router url params](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params)

Answer (score 1):

Is your intention to use a path something like that: `/items/11` then making fetch request using this `id`? If yes then change your second `Route` as:

```
<Route path="/items/:id" component={SingleGoods} />
```

So when you visit `/items/11` you can use this id in your `SingleGoods` component.

See: [React Router URL params](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params).

Answer (score 0):

For external requests, you can make substring or slice it

```
const {id} = useParams() -> :7
id.slice(1, id.length) -> 7
```